# Missing configuration for the issuer of security tokens error

Tags: authentication, claims-based-identity, sitefinity

I inherited an existing project without its development environment. I have UAT code and a backup of the Production database. I can run up the site locally via Visual Studio but have hit an authentication problem trying to setup a fresh standalone DEV server on AWS (single server, no load balancer). The doco indicates the Prod server is a dual server setup with a load balancer.

The front end site pages do display, although some search is not working. On trying to log into the backend pages, Chrome returns "The xxx page isn't working. xxx redirected you too many times." Using developer tools, I can see the page redirects back and forth between SWT?realm=... and sitefinity?wrap_defalted=true&wrap_access_token... On the second redirect response header there is "X-Authentication-Error:Missing configuration for the issuer of security tokens 'https://xxx/Sitefinity/Authenticate/SWT' "

I tried different values in the web.config lines:

```
<federatedAuthentication>
        <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="http://localhost" realm="http://localhost" requireHttps="true"/>
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="false"/>
</federatedAuthentication>
```

but that actually made things worse so I have reverted.

I checked all the settings mentioned in http://docs.sitefinity.com/administration-switch-to-claims-based-authentication and they seem to be set correctly. I don't really know what else I can check to get this working.

I found http://docs.sitefinity.com/administration-configure-security, but it does not seem like these settings are set (I don't have access to Prod server so can't confirm if it is actually setup with load balancing). I am currently using a 30 day trial license so am not sure if this is contributing to the problem. The official license is in the process of being transferred by the client. The domain name associated with the official license would be different to the domain my new server is currently running on.

I am also running version 8 code on a version 9 install of Sitefinity. I wanted to get it working before I tried to upgrade the code. I think there was also an assembly load to manifest mismatch when I tried upgrading my local version.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution: Don't mess with the SecurityConfig.config file.

```
<securityTokenIssuers>
    <add key="B886AA7BFB5515BA63F577A44BBEB5C7AE674035514D128BC397346B11F4C97A" encoding="Hexadecimal" membershipProvider="Default" realm="http://localhost" />
</securityTokenIssuers>
<relyingParties>
    <add key="B886AA7BFB5515BA63F577A44BBEB5C7AE674035514D128BC397346B11F4C97A" encoding="Hexadecimal" realm="http://localhost" />
</relyingParties>
```

Even though it is running on a server, the above lines should still point to localhost. It seems like these only need to be edited if you have a multi-server setup with an entirely separate STS.

I initially changed it to match the new domain name, but after some experimentation around adding localhost and HTTP variations, it seems like it works best with just localhost.

Even when I changed the web.config entry above to use the new domain as the issuer instead of localhost and the SecureConfig.config to specify only the new domain as the realms, it didn't seem to work. I guess the authentication must try to hit localhost specifically.